# How to get midnight of given date?

Tags: java, date

I need to know how to get current midnight from date.

For example I get "15.06.2012 16:40:20" and i need "15.06.2012 00:00:00".

```
public List<Game> getGamesByDate(Date day) throws SQLException {

    final Date startDate = day;

    //here I need to convert startDate to midnight somehow

    final Date endDate = new Date(day.getTime() + (23 * HOUR) + (59 * MINUTE));
    final List<Game> games = gameDAO.getGamesByDate(startDate, endDate);

    return games;

}
```

Comment: Not a duplicate IMO. That question is mostly about `Calender`s, this is about `Date`s.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [JodaTime](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) as such:

```
public List<Game> getGamesByDate(Date day) throws SQLException {

    final DateTime startDate = new DateTime(day).withTimeAtStartOfDay();

    ....

}
```

Comment: This is the best solution because for example in Brazil one day per year midnight does not exist. I am pretty sure that the OP has not thought about this detail, but maybe he is only concerned about local timestamps without time zone.

Comment: This is good solution and I think that i will use this one, but I set as best solution @Nfear because his solution is without any external library.

Comment: Personally I'd say avoiding Java Date and Calendar classes as much as possible is preferable ;)

Comment: Adding the [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) library is highly recommended. It is a high-quality well-worn library. In Java 8, the java.util.Date & .Calendar classes are being supplanted by new [java.time.* classes](http://download.java.net/jdk8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) because of deficiencies. Those new classes were inspired by Joda-Time. Until you can move to Java 8, use Joda-Time.

Answer (score 8):

```
Date startDate = day;
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setTime(startDate);
cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
Date newDate = cal.getTime();
```

Comment: Not a good answer. Some dates in some time zones have no midnight because of Daylight Saving Time (DST) or other anomalies. See the [correct answer by Wabs](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21139689/642706).

Answer (score 2):

You can use Calendar instance to get current year, month and day. then you can set the time whatever you want.

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
int dayOfMonth = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
int month = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);
int year = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
```

Comment: They would like to set the time on the given date to midnight, not the current date.